# Tomcat deploy in maven multi modules project

Tags: tomcat, maven, multi-module

I have maven project which contains two modules: jar and war. war-module depends on jar:

```
-pom
--jar
--war
```

Early I used org.codehaus.mojo tomcat-maven-plugin plugin to deploy my single war project by command:

```
mvn tomcat:deploy
```

But here this command doesn't work. How I can deploy war project in multi modules case?

**Solution was found**: [How can I deploy multiple wars using the tomcat plugin in maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189635/how-can-i-deploy-multiple-wars-using-the-tomcat-plugin-in-maven)

I added this in my child war project's pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>deploy</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>deploy</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And on parent project I can run:

```
mvn package tomcat:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to create a new module which contains the configuration for the tomcat-maven-plugin and may be (depending on your needs) it might be wise to create a separate profile for deployment in this case.

Comment: I have parent pom.xml file. Can I place this configuration here? Could you write example of this configuration?

Comment: I can recommend to read the following: https://github.com/khmarbaise/maui/tree/master/src/main/resources/it-example-container (this contains a full example for integration testing). But it used cargo2-maven-plugin instead of the tomcat plugin. But you can use the cargo2-plugin as well to deploy to tomcat. If you prefer to stick with the maven-tomcat-plugin you can use the mod-it module and change the configuration appropriately.  (Here is some description about it: http://khmarbaise.github.com/maui/it-example-container.html)