# Maven tomcat6-maven-plugin : Is it possible to add a GeoServer .war to it?

Tags: java, maven, geoserver, maven-tomcat-plugin

I use `tomcat6-maven-plugin` to run integration tests on my web application. This starts Tomcat and deploys my web application in it before running the tests. Works well!

But I'd like to run another web application, [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/), at the same time, for some new integration tests to work. What would be the best approach?

Is it possible to add a GeoServer .war to the Tomcat instance started using `tomcat6-maven-plugin`? How?

Here my current `tomcat6-maven-plugin` config :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/</path>
        <port>8087</port>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>run</id>
           <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>run</goal>
           </goals>
       </execution>
       <execution>
          <id>shutdown</id>
           <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>shutdown</goal>
           </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Why don't you deploy the GeoServer permanent on your test machine?

Comment: Andi, I'd like the integration tests to be *self-contained*. Let's say I want to re-initialize all the GeoServer configurations before running the tests, maybe I don't want this to also change a "permanent instance" running on the machine.

Comment: Is it really a case to configure the GeoServer every time new before the tests gonna be executed? Anyway, I guess [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189635/how-can-i-deploy-multiple-wars-using-the-tomcat-plugin-in-maven) is something for you.